# How to setup a crontab to execute at specific time

Tags: cron, settings

How can I set up my crontab to execute X script at 11:59PM every day without emailing me or creating any logs?

Right now my crontab looks something like this

```
@daily /path/to/script.sh
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you do crontab -e, try this:

```
59 23 * * * /usr/sbin/myscript > /dev/null
```

That means: At 59 Minutes and 23 Hours on every day (*) on every month on every weekday, execute myscript.

See **man crontab** for some more info and examples.

Answer (score 6):

Following up on [svrist's answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136/help-with-cronjobs#3145) depending on your shell, the 2>&1 should go *after* > /dev/null or you will still see the output from stderr.

The following will silence both stdout and stderr:

```
59 23 * * * /usr/sbin/myscript > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The following silences stdout, but stderr will still appear (via stdout):

```
59 23 * * * /usr/sbin/myscript 2>&1 > /dev/null
```

[The Advanced Bash Scripting Guide's chapter on IO redirection](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) is a good reference--search for 2>&1 to see a couple of examples.

Answer (score 5):

You will with the above response receive email with any text written to stderr. Some people redirect that away too, and make sure that the script writes a log instead.

```
... 2>&1 ....
```